# What is the time complexity of the following code snippet - Assume x is a global variable and “statement” takes O(n) time?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

[image: recurssion]
What is the time complexity of the following code snippet -  Assume x is a global variable and “statement” takes O(n) time?

Comment: Please avoid posting code as screenshot.

Comment: Did you just pasted code as image and answered yourself in 1 minute?

Answer (score 4):

Assume n=64.

- call 1 (n=64) : statement + A(n/2) = O(n) + O(A(n/2))
- call 2 (n/2=32) : statement + A(n/4) = O(n) + O(A(n/4))
- call 3 (n/4=16) : statement + A(n/8) = O(n) + O(A(n/8))
- call 4 (n/8=8) : statement + A(n/16) = O(n) + O(A(n/16))
- call 5 (n/16=4) : statement + A(n/32) = O(n) + O(A(n/32))
- call 6 (n/32=2) : statement + A(n/64) = O(n) + O(A(n/64))
- call 7 (n/64=1) : O(1)

Complexity = O(n)[statement] x log(n)[recursivity]

Conclusion : O(n.log(n))

Answer (score 1):

8* A(n/2) is a numerical multiplication and it takes O(1) time. 
So the recurrence relation for the above function is 
A(n)= A(n/2)+ O(n) 
Solving this with masters theorem we shall get 
A(n)= θ(n)

Comment: Why are you answering yourself one minute after asking your question?

Comment: I just found it very unique question, that's why i shared. Later I realized that it should not have happened. Anyway it's just a reference, won't happen again.

Comment: It is very ok to post a question and answer it if its helpful for others as well. This question is written so bad I doubt anyone will ever reach it by search.